# How to add listener in PyQT TableView's select all button?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qtableview

How do I attach a listener to PyQT's TableView's select all button?

PyQT TableView Sample

[image]

I have tried using below which only gets triggered when a cell is selected.

```
table.clicked.connect()
```

I have also tried adding listener to both header which only gets triggered when the columns or rows are selected

```
table.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked.connect()
table.verticalHeader().sectionClicked.connect()
```

They are all working as what they are intended to do, however I want to add listener to the top left button, the select all button. I can't seem to find from Qt's documentation that mentions this particular part of the button.

Code:

```
# Imported from Qt Designer created dialog
dialog = x.UI_Dialog()
table = dialog.tableSchedule
table.setModel(___) # I used my custom model that inherits from QtCore.QAbstractTableModel
table.clicked.connect(lambda: print('cell'))
table.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(lambda: print('col'))
table.verticalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(lambda: print('row'))
```

Answer (by @eyllanesc):
Get the corner button of the QTableView and add listener to it.

```
corner = table.findChild(QAbstractButton)
corner.clicked.connect(___)
```

Upon further inspection by getting the children of QTableView, these are the components:

- 3 QWidget
- QStyledItemDelegate
- 2 QHeaderView
- **QAbstractButton**
- QItemSelectionModel

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I added my code, anyways, I don't think the code has something to do with the question except clearing up that the table variable is an instance of QtWidgets.QTableView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That element of the corner is a `QAbstractButton` and there is no direct method to obtain it, a possible solution is to use `findChild()`:

```
corner = table.findChild(QAbstractButton)
```

Example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    table = QTableView()
    corner = table.findChild(QAbstractButton)

    table.clicked.connect(lambda: print('cell'))
    table.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(lambda: print('col'))
    table.verticalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(lambda: print('row'))
    corner.clicked.connect(lambda: print('corner'))

    model = QStandardItemModel(3, 4, table)
    table.setModel(model)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```